# Is there any block-cipher, format-preserving or similar encryption method with known cycle size? (without short-cut, with known source/runtime vars)

Tags: block-cipher, algorithm-design, format-preserving

E.g. given a $n$-bit message $m_0$ and an encryption function $f$

After applying the function $c$ times it will result in $m_0$ again.

$f^1(m_0) = f(m_0) = m_1$

$f^2(m_0) = f(f(m_0)) = f(m_1) = m_2$

..

$f^c(m_0) = m_c = m_0 $

On top of that an inverse function $f^{-1}$ with about equal computation time should exist as well. Also no short-cut in computing $m_i$ is allowed. It always either require the knowledge of  $m_{i-1}$ or $m_{i+1}$. Given two messages $m_i$, $m_j$ there should be no easy way to compute the difference $|i-j|$

Some example but with unknown cycle size would be AES.
I'm looking for an encryption method with known cycle size $c$ for all $m_0 \in  \{0,1\}^n$

### .

Further notes:

- $m_0$ will be a random number. An additional (fast) function is allowed
  which select only numbers with certain properties
- instead of $m_0$ a small known offset $k$ is allowed as well. With this
  $m_c$ can be different to $m_0$ but $m_{c+k} = m_{k}$
- 'hacking'-time should scale linear with cycle size $c$

---

**(Edit) Update: Additional requirements**

- an attacker has full access to the source code and runtime variables. All computations done at the local computer
- given two valid random messages $m'$ the chance should be high they are part of the same cycle (lets say $>10\%$ or at least $>0.4\%$). Or in other words different cycles are allowed but not much more than $10$ or $256$ as max limit (lower is better, except $<20$ would even be better than just $1$)
- exact cycle size don't need to be known. An approximation $\pm 50\%$ is sufficient (but if it contains multiple cycles those should be similar to each other ($\pm5\%$) )

Other than in most cryptography problems the relation in between should be encrypted not the messages themselves.

Comment: I'm pretty sure such a cipher wouldn't be secure because it would allow a distinguishing attack if the attacker had an encryption oracle.

Answer (score 2):

***CAUTION***: The following matches the requirement *"no short-cut in computing $m_i$ is allowed. It always either require the knowledge of  $m_{i-1}$ or $m_{i+1}$. Given two messages $m_i$, $m_j$ there should be no easy way to compute the difference $|i-j|$"* only with respect to an adversary not knowing the key. That goes straight against the added requirement that an adversary has *"access to runtime variables"*.

---

Well make an explicit construction from an $n$‑bit block cipher $E$ with the desired keyspace. Note $D$ the matching decryption.

Make a public partition of the blockspace $\{0,1\}^n$, assimilated to $[0,2^n)$ by e.g. big-endian convention, into intervals of size $c$ or slightly more according to the allowance for $k$. When $c$ is a power of two (e.g. $c=2^n/8$), that can be $2^n/c$ intervals of size $c$. When $\left\lfloor2^n/c\right\rfloor\ge(2^n\bmod c)$ [thus including any case with $c\le2^{n/2}$ ], that can be $\left\lfloor2^n/c\right\rfloor-(2^n\bmod c)$ intervals of size $c$, and $2^n\bmod c$ intervals of size $c+1$.

Define $h$ the bijection on $\{0,1\}^n$ that, to $x$ in a certain interval of said partition, associates the next integer in said interval if that's still in said interval, or the first integer in said interval otherwise. When $c$ is a power of two, that can be $h(x)\underset{\text{def}}=c\left\lfloor x/c\right\rfloor+(x+1\bmod c)$.

Define $f\underset{\text{def}}=D\circ h\circ E$. That is $f$ the bijection on $\{0,1\}^n$ with $f(x)=D(h(E(x)))$. That $f$ has the property *"After applying the function $c$ times* (within allowance) *it will result in $m_0$ again"* thought in the question, and has matching decryption $f^{-1}=D\circ h^{-1}\circ E$.

---

I conjecture that under the ideal cipher model for $E$, the resulting block cipher $f$ is secure when the number of (adaptive) queries an adversary can make remains negligible compared to $c$.

One slight implementation difficulty is avoiding side-channels in the implementation of $h$ and $h^{-1}$.

Comment: ty4answer, I'm not 100% sure if I understood it correct so I better ask. $c$ could also just be $2^n$, $2^{n-1}$ or $2^{n-2}$, right?

Comment: @J.Doe: yes, $c$ could be $2^n$, $2^{n-1}$, $2^{n-2}$, $2^{n-3}$, and any of these matches _"given two valid random messages the chance should be >10% they are part of the same cycle"_. However the new requirement that an adversary _"has access to runtime variables"_ plain kills my construction, for it allows a shortcut.

Comment: ye, sorry about changing. However interesting answer. Maybe it can be combined with homomorphic encryption. That could lead to unknown value of $x$ in $h$.